# Remove last n rows for 0 by id and then tail last n elements by Id in R

Tags: r

[final dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLggr.png)I have a dataset as attached.

[image]

I want to remove all Last 0s in
binary by Id, and then select tail 3 for
by id. (Note:  for Id 2 only remainng 2
w5 and w6 ). It will be like the final dataset.

Is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: please format your question

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: This is better, but what do you mean by "select tail 3 for by id"? The only difference between Final and Original dataset I see is that Final has all trailing zeros removed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
ID = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 8))
week = c(2:9, 5:8, 13:20)
binary = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

dataset = data.frame(ID, week, binary)

> dataset
   ID week binary
1   1    2      0
2   1    3      1
3   1    4      1
4   1    5      1
5   1    6      1
6   1    7      0
7   1    8      0
8   1    9      0
9   2    5      1
10  2    6      1
11  2    7      0
12  2    8      0
13  3   13      1
14  3   14      1
15  3   15      1
16  3   16      0
17  3   17      0
18  3   18      1
19  3   19      0
20  3   20      0
```

Solution:

```
# Split dataset by ID
byGroupDf = split(dataset, ID)

# For each grouped dataset, take only rows up till the last row where ID not equal to 0
byGroupFinal = lapply(byGroupDf, function(x) tail(x[1:max(which(x$binary != 0)),], 3))

# Combine the grouped datasets
FinalDf = do.call(rbind, byGroupFinal)

> FinalDf
     ID week binary
1.3   1    4      1
1.4   1    5      1
1.5   1    6      1
2.9   2    5      1
2.10  2    6      1
3.16  3   16      0
3.17  3   17      0
3.18  3   18      1
```

Comment: I have attached a right one for final dataset. byGroupFinal = lapply(byGroupDf, function(x) tail(x[1:max(which(x$binary != 0)),],3)) .  and just need to add tail 3 in your code then can get what I  want . thanks

Comment: @MLM Edited my answer. Is this what you want?